# How to use filter() and includes() with localeCompare for avoid accents

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I’m looking for a way to filter a table while avoiding accent problems.

```
let options = ['Hello', 'Hého', 'Heïho'];

filterOptions(filterValue) {
      this.filteredOptions = this.options.filter(
      option => option.includes( filterValue )
   )
 },
```

With the above function, when I search in `options` by writing the word "Heho", it doesn't return any results because I didn't put an accent.

I tried using this, but it doesn't work at all

```
filterOptions(filterValue) {
            this. filteredOptions = this. options.filter(
                option => option.includes( filterValue.localeCompare(option, undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0 )
            )
        },
```

Do you know how I can filter my table avoiding accents?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I found a simpler solution

```
filterOptions(filterValue) {
        this. filteredOptions = this. options.filter(
            option => option.toLowerCase().includes( filterValue.toLowerCase() ) 
        )
    },
```

I switch all the strings to lowercase for compare

Comment: this does not answer the original question because toLowerCase() does not get rid of the accents.

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter using the logic, (use undefined or 'en'). Problem with your code is, it is comparing if the array includes value true or false, based on what the localeCompare returns.

```
options.filter(o => o.localeCompare('Heho', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }) === 0)
```